# Can Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) be configured to use sshPublicKey ldap attributes

Tags: ldap, ssh-keys, team-foundation-server

We have a very mixed environment as many enterprises should, our users are in Microsoft AD, our servers are a mix of windows and linux.

As such, we use the `sshPublicKey` ldap attribute to store ssh keys for linux authentication and gitlab.

**Does TFS allow you to specify this ldap attribute for accessing the TFS Hosted  git repo**

Running TFS 2015

This is the version of git packaged with TFS, and not any external git repos.

Comment: TFS is authenticated with Active Directory. You can only add AD accounts and groups to TFS.

Answer (score 2):

### If you are accessing Git in TFS

No, you have to use the TFS provided SSH Key. TFS will create SSH keys for users so that they can access the content.

[image]

This is built I to TFS. Users that want to access Git repos in TFS should go to their profile and create one.!

**note: If your ldap SSH key is linked to an AD account you can give that AD account permission to TFS.**

### If you are accessing GitLab from Team Build in TFS

Yes, you can do one of two things:

1. *Add the SSH Key to the Build Variables* - you can then call out to GitLab using that variable.
2. *Create a GitLab Service Credential* - Using a extension you can add a GitLab connection to your Team Project and use the same creds with any build.

If you mean something else then please update your question for clarity.

Comment: specifically the first,  accessing a git repo on tfs from my machine via ssh

Comment: added some clarity this is not for external repos using builds

Comment: Then create an SSH key for your user account and use that as described.